# How can I summarize a set of records into one line where only one record in a column has text and all others are null?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have invoice data stored in a SQL database and I need a summary query to bring up the Invoice Number, PO number, Date, and Invoice Amount in a single line using an MS Access Query. Unfortunately, the customer PO number is only on one line of the invoice data and pops up on the query result like this.

| Invoice Date | Invoice # | PO Number | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/11/22 | 12345 | NULL | $23.00 |
| 8/11/22 | 12345 | 456 | $00.00 |

I need the output to look like this instead:

| Invoice Date | Invoice # | PO Number | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/11/22 | 12345 | 456 | $23.00 |

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT  
    [Invoice Date],
    [Invoice #],
    [PO Number],
    FORMAT$(Sum([Amount])),'$#,##0.00') AS [Amount]
FROM [Invoice Details]
GROUP BY 
    [Invoice Date],
    [Invoice #],
    [PO Number]
HAVING 
    [INVOICE DATE] BETWEEN [8/11/2022] AND [8/11/2022]
ORDER BY 
    [INVOICE #]
```

I am still a novice when it comes to SQL queries and am not sure what I am missing here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hello Suman, I have edited my question to show my expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you can exclude `[PO Number]` column from your `GROUP BY` and just take the greater value in each group. I think you can use :

```
SELECT  
    [Invoice Date],
    [Invoice #],
    MAX(Nz([PO Number], 0)) AS [PO Number],
    FORMAT$(Sum([Amount])),'$#,##0.00') AS [Amount]
FROM [Invoice Details]
GROUP BY 
    [Invoice Date],
    [Invoice #],
HAVING 
    [INVOICE DATE] BETWEEN [8/11/2022] AND [8/11/2022]
ORDER BY 
    [INVOICE #]
```

[Nz](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) is replacing `Null` by `0` here.

Answer (score 0):

You have very limited example input, but assuming TABLE1

This will work

```
SELECT Amounts.[Invoice Date], Amounts.[Invoice #], [PO Numbers].[PO Number], Amounts.Amount
FROM Table1 AS Amounts 
INNER JOIN Table1 AS [PO Numbers] 
ON (Amounts.[Invoice Date] = [PO Numbers].[Invoice Date]) AND (Amounts.[Invoice #] = [PO Numbers].[Invoice #])
WHERE ((([PO Numbers].[PO Number]) Is Not Null) AND ((Amounts.[PO Number]) Is Null));
```

Looks like this in the query window

[image]